# Pronic Integers in String/Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, infinite-loop

The program must accept an integer N as the input. The program must print all the pronic integers formed by series of continuously occurring digits (in the same order) in N as the output.

The pronic integers can be represented as n*(n+1).

**Note: The pronic integers must be printed in the order of their occurrence.**

**Boundary Condition(s):**

**1 <= N <= 10^20**

***Max execution time: 4000 milliseconds***

**Input Format:**
The first line contains N.
**Output Format:**
The first line contains the pronic integers separated by a space.
Example Input/Output 1:
**Input:**

93042861

**Output:**

930 30 0 42 2 6

**Explanation:**

30 * 31 = 930

5 * 6 = 30

0 * 1 = 0

6 * 7 = 42

1 * 2 = 2

2 * 3 = 6

**Example Input/Output 2:**

**Input:**

247025123524

**Output:**

2 702 0 2 12 2 2352 2

**Explanation:**

1 * 2 = 2

26 * 27 = 702

0 * 1 = 0

1 * 2 = 2

3 * 4 = 12

1 * 2 = 2

48 * 49 = 2352

1 * 2 = 2

```
def ispro(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        if i*(i+1)==n: return 1
    return 0
def pro(a):
    n=len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if(a[i:j]!=""):
                if(a[i:j]==str(int(a[i:j]))):
                    if(ispro(int(a[i:j]))):
                        print(a[i:j],end=" ")
a=input().strip()
pro(a)
```

**In this code, time limit exceeds for string length greater than 10.**

***You may edit this code or create your own code to solve this problem.***

Answer (score 1):

N = 10^20 meaning there are 20 digits possible. This means we have to check 20 * (19) / 2 --> 190 possible numbers to check if they are pronic. Let us denote one of these 20 possible numbers as PRN.

The maximum number of digits PRN can be is 20 - we obviously cannot brute force each possible number (that would take 10^20 iterations). Instead, we can binary search over N, where N * (N+1) = PRN.

You can search up binary search to learn more about it, if you don't know already about it. Essentially, if our guess (N) is too big, we make N smaller, otherwise we make N bigger. We do this until N * (N+1) = PRN (meaning PRN is pronic), or there is no possible solution - so we move on.

This binary search would take log(n) time. So for a max of 20 digits, 67 iterations. And for over 190 possible numbers, this would be 12730 checks - which would easily fit in the time constraints. There are probably more mathematically beautiful solutions, but this will do.