pronic number check for N
The program must accept an integer N as the input. The program must print all the pronic integers formed by series of continuously occurring digits (in the same order) in N as the output.
Note: The pronic integers must be printed in the order of their occurrence. The pronic integers can be represented as n*(n+1).
Boundary Condition(s): 1 <= N <= 10^20
Input Format: The first line contains N.
Output Format: The first line contains the pronic integers separated by a space.
Example Input/Output 1:
Input: 93042861 Output: 930 30 0 42 2 6
Explanation: 30 * 31 = 930 5 * 6 = 30 0 * 1 = 0 6 * 7 = 42 1 * 2 = 2 2 * 3 = 6
Example Input/Output 2:
Input: 247025123524 Output: 2 702 0 2 12 2 2352 2
import math
def is_pronic(number):
    if number==0:
        return True
    x=int(math.sqrt(number))
    return x*(x+1)==number
def f_pronic_numbers(number):
    char=str(number)
    length=len(char)
    # pronic_number=[]
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(i+1,length+1):
            if is_pronic(int(char[i:j])) and (char[i:j]==str(int(char[i:j]))):
                print(char[i:j],end=" ")

n=int(input())
f_pronic_numbers(n)

For this only the 3 test case have been passed I don't what may be the 1 test case that failed.

[ask] and [mre]

What input value causes the test(s) to fail?

the test case is hidden so i dont know exactly what is the test case that causing the problem

@NishanthTamil Did my answer solve the problem?

no brother still that hidden case is not solved

@NishanthTamil I suspect that your understanding of the problem statement is flawed. Is this problem available online somewhere?

FWIW, this question has been set before on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75130452/pronic-integers-in-string-number - the only addition is a time limit of 4000 milliseconds. The problem there was time-limit-exception (implying "faster method needed"). A shame that @Nishanth Tamil doesn't give us a little more detail. It's straightforward to reduce the number of tests (in most cases).

As well as using math.isqrt() to avoid floating point inaccuracies, you can also make your code more efficient as follows:
from math import isqrt
from typing import Iterator
from random import randint
import time

def is_pronic(number: int) -> bool:
    x = isqrt(number)
    return x * (x + 1) == number


def f_pronic_numbers(number: str) -> Iterator[int]:
    length = len(number)
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(i + 1, length + 1):
            if is_pronic(n := int(number[i:j])):
                yield n
                if n == 0:
                    break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = str(randint(0, 10**20))
    print(n)
    start = time.perf_counter()
    print(*f_pronic_numbers(n))
    duration = time.perf_counter() - start
    print(f"{duration=:.6f}s")

Example output:
8132220462423414970
132 32220 2 2 2 20 0 462 6 2 42 2 4970 0
duration=0.000064s


You have to explain what failed, the is_iconic function is correct, I made only a little change to it
def is_pronic(number):
    if number == 0:
        return True
    x = math.isqrt(number)   # round the square root number downwards to the nearest integer
    return x*(x + 1) == number

If your problem is the possible duplicate of pronic numbers here the change I made to the f_pronic_numbers function
def f_pronic_numbers(number):
    char=str(number)
    length=len(char)
    # upper boundary condition
    if length > 20:   # 10^20=100000000000000000000 with 21 digits
        char = char[:20]
    prone_numbers = []
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(i + 1, length + 1):
            if is_pronic(int(char[i:j])):   
                if int(char[i:j]) not in prone_numbers:
                    prone_numbers.append(int(char[i:j]))
                    #print(char[i:j], end=" ")
    return prone_numbers

I hope it helped.

i have tried this but still it doesn't pass that hidden case

@NishanthTamil You need to be more specific about that hidden case. What is that case, what should be the result and what you get with this function.

@NishanthTamil If you don´t know what the test case is how do you know it´s not solved. How did you test it ? Do you use a specific number or do you want a number that gives a certain result ?

i think your solution has worked thanks for the help

this question is on the skillrack website in the list of questions asked in tcs
